# Connecting to containers IP address is impossible in Docker for Windows

Tags: networking, docker, hyper-v

This issue happens when you install latest Docker for Windows that uses Hyper-V.

However you can see ips in `docker network inspect bridge` output:

```
"Containers": {
            "...": {
                "Name": "dockerdevenvironment_rabbit_1",
                "EndpointID": "...",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "...": {
                "Name": "webserver",
                "EndpointID": "...",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "...": {
                "Name": "dockerdevenvironment_mongo_1",
                "EndpointID": "...",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
```

You can't even ping them or connect them in any way.

Comment: When you say you can't connect, what does that mean? Are you running a container and can't bring it up in the browser? Did you expose a port to the container? What do you see when you run docker ps? Have you tried connecting to http://localhost? That's where Docker for Windows containers are supposed to be.

Comment: it does not connect to localhost, even for their own example (docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default dockerNAT assigns 10.0.75.0/24 to MobyLinuxVM.
Docker inside MobyLinuxVM assigns to containers IP addresses in range 172.17.0.0/16. You have to alter route tables to access containers IP address:

`route add  172.17.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.0.75.2 -p`

source: https://forums.docker.com/t/connecting-to-containers-ip-address/18817

Comment: This would only be if someone were trying to access the container from another machine though. Localhost should still work.

Comment: @ManoMarks but it does not. even for their own nginx example

Comment: As my main network is using the 10.0.0.0/8 network, Docker assigned the 192.168.4.0/24 network to MobyLinuxVM. And looks like you still have to map the ports in order to have access to the container ones...

Comment: Tried that both using Hyper-V and WSL2 and it didn't work. I didn't get where `10.0.75.2` comes from, maybe I should use a different value?